# Delay in opening opening of android in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, android-activity

I am moving from one activity to another containing 6 more fragments in that activity , I have used navhost for it but it is delaying the transaction. Activity is opening late
providing code below

```
  {val intent = Intent(requireActivity(), ItemDetailActivity::class.java)
                intent.putExtra(Constants.SelectedBoardIds, gson.toJson(listOfBoardIds))
                intent.putExtra(Constants.projectId, gson.toJson(idOfProject))
                intent.putExtra(Constants.projectList, gson.toJson(mutableListOfBoard))
                intent.putExtra(Constants.kanban, gson.toJson(item))
                val options = ActivityOptions.makeCustomAnimation(
                    requireActivity(),
                    R.anim.slide_from_right,
                    R.anim.no_anim
                )
                startActivity(intent,options.toBundle())
            }
```

I want to tell y this delay is coming

Comment: Please, provide the code causing the delay and update your question

Comment: Am unable to put the code here can you tell your email so that i could contact you there

Comment: @ItzDavi hello I have added the code

Comment: Did you check your animation duration ?

Comment: if am not adding animation still it taking time

Comment: Why not parsing your lists BEFORE creating the intent ? Try parsing everything and then assign your parsed lists to your intent

Comment: I tried that as well .. I have activity containing 6 other fragments. I guess that cause problem

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.